# Como crear archivos csv a partir de de una agrupación o un filtro?

Tags: pandas

[image: Quiero guardar estación por estación en formato csv]

Requiero guardar estación por estación por ejemplo: ABELARDO.csv

Comment: Al no disponer de tus datos para pruebas, no garantizo que lo siguiente funcione, pues lo hago de memoria, pero creo que podría ser algo del estilo de `grouped.reset_index().query('Estacion=="ABELARDO R."').to_csv("ABELARDO.csv")`

Comment: O, si no quieres especificar el nombre completo de la estación, sino sólo parte, `grouped.reset_index().query('Estacion.str.contains("ABELARDO")').to_csv("ABELARDO.csv")`. Por cierto que deberías _sanear_ los nombres. "CAÑADA HONDA" aparece escrita de cinco formas diferentes, ninguna correcta.

Comment: Hola abulafia: Para sanear los nombres o quitarles tildes sería otro tema a parte?

Comment: Sí, yo pondría otra pregunta. Además la respuesta puede ser batante compleja...

Comment: Muchas Gracias abulafia